# Error occurs when I run command "rosbag play example.bag". Could not find library corresponding to plugin rosbag/NoEncryptor

Tags: c++, plugins, ros, rosbag

I am currently learning how to use rosbag, but when I run the command "rosbag play D:\summer_project\20200619_123634.bag", I got the following error:

```
C:\Windows\System32>rosbag play D:\summer_project\20200619_123634.bag
[ INFO] [1593471808.789562700]: Opening D:\summer_project\20200619_123634.bag
[FATAL] [1593471809.093414800]: Could not find library corresponding to plugin rosbag/NoEncryptor. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
```

I did some research online and I need to do something with the NoEncryptor. Here is the link I found: http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib;
https://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/rosbag_storage/html/c++/classrosbag_1_1NoEncryptor.html;

I have never use c language, so i got no clue for the setup process. What do I need to do with the .cpp file and .h file? If anyone could give me some ideas or suggestions, that would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you have not sourced ROS correctly or you have a corrupted ROS installation. The plugin is part of ros_comm which should be installed.

Comment: I followed this tutorial(http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Windows). And it make successfully. I am not sure where it went wrong tho, is there anyway for me to add the plugin manually?

Comment: I have reinstalled the ros, but I still got the same error...

Comment: Could you post an answer if you did solve your problem? I am having exactly the same issue and I believe it has something to with ROS on Windows

Comment: Hi Gokberk, I am still in the process of solving the issue. I also posted the issue to ROS Answer, and they are investigating this. https://github.com/ms-iot/ROSOnWindows/issues/237

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same problem by using Ubuntu 18.04 inside WSL. I suggest building ROS inside WSL instead of trying to use native Windows ROS build. It is still too unstable to get any work done without encountering an error, wastes too much time.

Here have a look at this: [WSL Developement with VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl)

And this for ROS on WSL tutorial: [ROS on WSL](https://janbernloehr.de/2017/06/10/ros-windows)